# Dual curvature in Einstein-Cartan theory

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, curvature

The curvature 2-form in the theory is

$$\rho^{ab}=\frac{1}{2}R^{ab}_{\alpha\beta}\,dx^{\alpha}\wedge dx^{\beta},$$

where the curved indices $\alpha,\beta$ are suppressed.

The curvature satisfies the Bianchi idetity

$$d\rho^{ab}+\omega^a_{\,c}\,\wedge\,\rho^{cb}-\rho^{ac}\wedge\,\omega_c^{\,b}=0,$$
which then defines the Lorentz covariant derivative
$$D \rho^{ab}=0.$$

In terms of the curved indices one can then see that

$$D_{[\mu}R_{\alpha\beta]}^{\quad ab}=0,$$
or equivalently
$$\epsilon^{\sigma\alpha\beta\mu}\,D_{\mu}R_{\alpha\beta}^{\quad ab}=0.$$

Now I want to know if the dual curvature can also have a vanishing covariant derivative
$$D\star\rho^{ab}=0.$$

Computing the Hodge dual we have
$$\star\rho^{ab}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|g|}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\sigma}(\rho^{\alpha\beta})^{ab}\,dx^{\gamma}\wedge\,dx^{\sigma}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{|g|}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\sigma}R^{\alpha\beta ab}\,dx^{\gamma}\wedge\,dx^{\sigma}.$$

If one is to take the covaraint derivative of this, in terms of the curved indices we will have something of the form
$$D\star\rho^{ab}=\frac{1}{4}D^{\sigma}\left(\sqrt{|g|}\right)\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\sigma}R^{\alpha\beta a b}+\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{|g|}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\sigma}D^{\sigma}R^{\alpha\beta a b}.$$

The second term is zero by the Bianchi identity, but unless the connection is metric compatible (in this case it is not as I am considering the case of non-vanishing torsion), the first term is non-zero and we have that

$$D\star\rho^{ab}=\frac{1}{4}D^{\sigma}\left(\sqrt{|g|}\right)\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\sigma}R^{\alpha\beta a b},$$
and so is non-vanishing.

Is this correct, or am I missing something that can make it vanish?

Comment: $\nabla_{[a}R_{bc]de}=0$ is equivalent to $\nabla^{a\star}R_{abcd}=0$

Comment: I am considering the torsionful case with Lorentz covariant derivative. Are you sure this is satisfied in this case?